# Is it necessary to run a bitcoin node in order to interact with bitcoin blockchain?

Tags: ruby, bitcoin, blockchain, bitcoind

Was looking at libraries for bitcoin node implementation like [bitcoin-ruby](https://github.com/lian/bitcoin-ruby) and [toshi](https://github.com/coinbase/toshi). I guess my question is quite basic but I'm a newby here: Is it necessary to download the entire blockchain (and even set a node) in order interact with it as sending/receiving transactions, getting block data or create an address?

Answer (score 2):

Things you can do offline, without syncing fully with the blockchain

- Create new bitcoin addresses
- Create transactions to be sent if you already have funds in some of your addresses

Things you can do with a connected, without syncing fully with the blockchain -

- Send a transaction (broadcast it)

Check out implementations of SPV wallets such as breadwallet to know  more.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to interact with the bitcoin network without downloading the entire blockchain.

You should check how to interact with the peers in the [bitcoin developer guide p2p section](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-guide#p2p-network).

There are also a lot of libraries that allow you to interact with the bitcoin network, for example, with [bitcore p2p](https://bitcore.io/api/p2p/) you can interact with a pool of peers with:

```
var Pool = require('bitcore-p2p').Pool;
var Networks = require('bitcore-lib').Networks;

var pool = new Pool({network: Networks.livenet});

// connect to the network
pool.connect();

// attach peer events
pool.on('peerinv', function(peer, message) {
  // a new peer message has arrived
});

// Send a message, as soon as the response arrives, the pool will emit the related event.
// If your request is a getheaders message https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#getheaders
// you should listen for 'peerheaders'
pool.sendMessage(message)

// will disconnect all peers
pool.disconnect()
```

For checking an address balance, if you don't download the entire blockchain, you should download the [header chain](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-guide#headers-first). When you want to check if an address is or not in a block, you can request a [merkleblock](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#filterload.2C_filteradd.2C_filterclear.2C_merkleblock).

[Here](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-guide#simplified-payment-verification-spv) and [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/32529/what-is-a-thin-client) you can find more about the spv clients.